# Проблема в коде Python IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Существует такой вот код на Python, VkBotLongPoll:

```
if bodyone[1] == 'test':
                sender (cid, 'бегу по тропикне лялялялял')
```

При использовании иногда может выдасть ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b:\Downloads\botforyuma.py", line 66, in <module>
    if bodyone[1] == 'test':
IndexError: list index out of range
PS C:\Users\Kiril>
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: в том, что с списке меньше двух элементов

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к ответу CrazyElf хочу отметить, что можно использовать конструкцию `try/except`:

```
try:
    if bodyone[1] == 'test':
        sender (cid, 'бегу по тропикне лялялялял')
except IndexError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверяйте предварительно длину списка, если ли там достаточно элементов, чтобы обращаться по такому индексу:

```
if len(bodyone) > 1 and bodyone[1] == 'test':
                sender (cid, 'бегу по тропикне лялялялял')
```